# iOS Test Suite crashes after running xctest.xctwaiter

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest, xctestexpectation

This has been happening with xcode 9 and xcode10 now, using Quick and XCTest for unit tests they will run all the way fine but throw an exception/crash at the end. If I continue the tests will succeed.

[image]

I've spent so many hours trying to figure this out with no luck. I don't see anything helpful in the logs or stack trace. It's a big code base with 2,000+ tests so it's hard to figure out if it's just one causing it. I've tried:

- Removing all files from test target, adding 1 by 1, at some point it breaks again but moving back to previous OK version now starts to fail.
- deleting all async tests from both Quick and XCTest
- Deleting all XCTEst cases, to see if it's an issue of both in 1 target.

Comment: The Xcode 10 release notes state that exceptions can now only be waited on once per test and that this will now be enforced. Please can you post the test code and exception message?

Comment: I don't get an exception when this happens, the closest I can find to an exception is the screenshot attached before. There also isn't just a piece of code as I haven't found one test or block of code that causes this. I know this is super vague, but at this point I'm hoping for someone who has seen this in the past and can chime in, I don't expect anyone to be able to help troubleshoot..

Comment: @JDM Did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm encountering this as well. Seems completely random. Branches with the exact same unit tests pass without incident. But then I have a developer who seems to get unlucky more than others. Deleting a specific unit test "fixes" the problem, then re-adding the same test results in... success? Why? Until it breaks again, for literally no reason.
 
Anyone have any ideas on this? @JDM did you ever find anything?